# Writing D-Bus service with pygobject?

Tags: python, dbus, pygobject

I'm trying to write a D-Bus service. But I'm confused about the python
packages **[pygobject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io)** and **[dbus-python](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/index.htm)**.

Is it possible to write a D-Bus service with pygobject alone (without using
dbus-python)? My understanding was that pygobject provides everything
that dbus-python does. Is this correct? Or do I need dbus-python?

I succeeded in calling methods of other programs via D-Bus by just using
pygobject. But how do I provide my own interface and own methods as a service in D-Bus? As far as I understand I have to inherit my interface class from
`Gio.DBusInterfaceSkeleton`[1]. But how do I export my own methods?

[1] https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gio-2.0/classes/DBusInterfaceSkeleton.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to write D-Bus services in pygobject because stable versions of [gobject-introspection](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) don't seem to properly detect all of the virtual methods, in particular the `get_vtable` method. You'll notice that `do_get_vtable` is missing from [the generated API docs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/DBusInterfaceSkeleton.html#virtual-methods). I tried building gobject-introspection 1.59.4, and it is able to extract proper typelib information from glib 2.58.1, so perhaps there is hope for the future.